# How to implement a JWT Token Authentication on Swashbuckle in .Net Core?

Tags: c#, swagger, asp.net-core-webapi, swashbuckle

I am having trouble implementing JWT token authentication in Swagger UI/ Swashbuckle.

I implemented this code in the `Startup.cs` as an example on the documentation.

In the method **ConfigureServices**

```
        _ = services.AddSwaggerGen(c =>
          {
              c.SwaggerDoc("v1", new OpenApiInfo
              {
                  Title = "Proyekto4Juan API",
                  Version = "v1"
              });

              c.AddSecurityDefinition("Bearer", new OpenApiSecurityScheme
              {
                  In = ParameterLocation.Header,
                  Description = "Please insert token",
                  Name = "Authorization",
                  Type = SecuritySchemeType.Http,
                  BearerFormat = "JWT",
                  Scheme = "bearer"
              });

              c.AddSecurityRequirement(new OpenApiSecurityRequirement {
                  {
                      new OpenApiSecurityScheme
                      {
                          Reference = new OpenApiReference
                          {
                              Type = ReferenceType.SecurityScheme,
                              Id = "Bearer"
                          }
                      },
                      new string[]{}
                  }
              });
          });

        services.AddAuthorization(auth =>
        {
            auth.AddPolicy("Bearer", new AuthorizationPolicyBuilder()
                .AddAuthenticationSchemes(JwtBearerDefaults.AuthenticationScheme‌​)
                .RequireAuthenticatedUser().Build());
        });

        services.AddAuthentication(JwtBearerDefaults.AuthenticationScheme)
                .AddJwtBearer(JwtBearerDefaults.AuthenticationScheme, options => Configuration.Bind("JwtSettings", options))
                .AddCookie(CookieAuthenticationDefaults.AuthenticationScheme, options => Configuration.Bind("CookieSettings", options));
```

And on the **Configure** method

```
 public void Configure(IApplicationBuilder app, IWebHostEnvironment env)
        {
            if (env.IsDevelopment())
            {
                app.UseDeveloperExceptionPage();
            }

            app.UseHttpsRedirection();

            app.UseRouting();

            app.UseAuthorization();
            app.UseAuthentication();

            app.UseEndpoints(endpoints =>
            {
                _ = endpoints.MapControllers();
            });

            app.UseStatusCodePages();

            app.UseCors(x => x
                .AllowAnyOrigin()
                .AllowAnyMethod()
                .AllowAnyHeader());


            app.UseSwagger();

            app.UseSwaggerUI(c => {
                c.DefaultModelExpandDepth(0);
                c.DefaultModelsExpandDepth(-1);
                c.SwaggerEndpoint("/swagger/v1/swagger.json", "V1 API test");
                c.RoutePrefix = string.Empty;
            });
        }
```

But when I test the my Actions on the Controller using the Swagger UI.

[image: Error Response 401]

On the Endpoint, I decorated my Action like this.

```
    [HttpPost]
    [Route("DestroyUserSession")]
    [Authorize]
    public async Task<ResultModel> DestroyUserSession([FromBody] string userID)
    {
      //..... Do Something
    }
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I wrote a complete JWT token generation and verification process, you can refer to the following:

[Swagger verification authority](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/69963490/swagger-verification-authority)

Comment: It didn't help. same result Sir

Comment: I update the answer, you can refer to it, it may be helpful to you

Comment: Eyyy! Thank you!